# Inserting elements into a database table through using ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-connection

I have been dealing with connecting to a database from an ASP.NET page. After I had filled the associated the registration form I have prepared, when I click the complete registration I am encountering an error:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
       using (SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("server=BerkPC-IV; Initial Catalog=Okul; Integrated Security=true;"))
       {
           using (SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand())
           {
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@midname", TextBox2.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", TextBox3.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", TextBox4.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", TextBox5.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox6.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adress", TextBox7.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwod", TextBox8.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox9.Text);

                try
                {
                    baglanti.Open();
                    komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should be posting the entire exception with the stack trace and not just the image. It helps in debugging.

Comment: That's ok, that edit wouldnt be approved anyways :P

Comment: You really should move your connection information to your config file. This is going to be a nightmare when the sql server changes. Also, I am just going to leave this here. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a db connectivity issue. In your connection string you have not specified the db username and password.

```
new SqlConnection("server=BerkPC-IV; Initial Catalog=Okul; Integrated Security=true;"))
```

which mean the exception must be thrown on execution of this line `baglanti.Open();`